# A variable in PHP that get increased by himself?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

A weird problem.
I'm trying to use [medoo](http://medoo.in/) with sqlite file to get some data. I'm receving a multidimensional array.  I've checked with `print_r` that the data is really in it.

This is the `print_r` output (short version):

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => aaa ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => bbb ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => ccc ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => ddd ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => eee ) ...
)
```

This is my code:

```
$datas = $database->select("suppliers","*");
print_r ($datas);
$length=count($datas);
$i = 0;
while ( $i < $length ) {
    echo $i;
    echo '<a href="edit_sup.php?sup='.$datas[$i]["id"].">".$datas[$i]["name"]."</a><br/>";
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    }
```

The problem is that not all the data get printed!
While trying to print the var `$i`, I've discovered that before and after the `a href` the value is different! For example, the output is something like that:

```
0 bbb
21 ddd
43 fff
```

As you can see, in the first line `aaa` supposed to be printed - but `bbb` is printed instead, and `aaa` isn't printed at all! (and so on...)

Any idea why this is happening? thanks.

Comment: That's not possible for the code and data you provided.

Comment: I can't see how your code skips array elements. I even tried it out here, which appears to print the desired output: https://3v4l.org/0feUa

Comment: @zerkms     That is possible ***considering that the line echoing the link was malformed.*** He was supposed to do **$datas[$i]["id"] . '">' .** but he probably missed it and did **$datas[$i]["id"] . ">" .** instead. In other words, the HREF attribute has a Problem... ***If he checks the Source code, all of the values will be there only malformed and thus cannot be displayed.***

Comment: @zerkms, ok amiga, not like i was joking or anything.

Comment: hahah touche, sir. well played.

Comment: @Keiji, I don't know why in the link you provided the **same code** is working, but in my computer the result isn't the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try another kind of Looping Construct like so:

```
    <?php

    $datas = $database->select("suppliers","*");
    print_r ($datas);

    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        echo '<a href="edit_sup.php?sup='. $data["id"] .'">' . $data["name"] . "</a><br/>";
    }
```

Although there is nothing essentially wrong with using a while loop, You seemed to mix up your single and double quotes so, even the While Loop could still work when done rightly like so:

```
    while ( $i < $length ) {
        echo $i;
        // THE ISSUE WAS JUST WITH THE SWAPPING OF SINGLE QUOTES WITH DOUBLE QUOTES...
        echo '<a href="edit_sup.php?sup=' . $datas[$i]["id"] . '">' . $datas[$i]["name"] . "</a><br/>";
        echo $i;
        $i++;
    }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Great, thanks! Those little things that make you nuts and you don't understand what you are missing...

Comment: BTW, in the beginning I used `foreach`, but when this didn't work iv'e tried to use `while` because I didn't know where the problem is...